# marginal pdf of a exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Problem
Let $X$ have the pdf $f(x)=e^{-x}$, $x>0$ and $Y$ have the pdf $f(y)=e^{-y}$, $y>0$. Assume that X and Y are independent Find the pdf of $U=X+Y$?

Solution

Since X and Y are indep. it follows that $f(x,y)=e^{-x-y}$. Now I need to $f_u(u)=?$. I was told to use this from the notes

Assuming that $U=X+Y$ and that $V=Y$ then $$f_u(u)=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(u-v,v) dv$$ $$=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u+v-v} dv$$ $$=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u} dv$$ But that's inifnity. And if I substitute $U=X+Y=X+V$ then I feel that be wrong too. Am I missing something here? Not very sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that $U=X+Y$ and $V=Y$, indeed 
$$\begin{align}f_U(u)&=\int_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(u-v,v)\,\mathrm d v\\&=\int_0^\infty f_{X}(u-v)f_Y(v)\,\mathrm d v\end{align}$$
However, $f_X(u-v)$ is non-zero only for range $0<v<u$. As a result, the limits of the integration will be $0$ and $u$, leading to:
$$\begin{align}f_U(u)&=\int_0^u f_{X}(u-v)f_Y(v)\,\mathrm dv\\&=\int_0^u e^{-u+v-v}\,\mathrm d v\\& =ue^{-u}\end{align}$$